# Update component view after callback received on service

Tags: angular

I am calling a function from service in component. Service will get data from sdk and response in callback function. I'm not able to send callback response to component.

**Component.ts**

```
async publishSession() {

    let publishCallback = await this.myService.publishStream();
    
  }
```

**Service.ts**

```
callbackResponse;
publishStream(publishCapabilities, mediaConstraints) {
    this.session = session;

    var videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    var publishOptions = {
      publishToken: publishing,
      mediaConstraints: mediaConstraints,
      videoElement: videoElement
    };

    return this.sdk.publishToChannel(publishOptions, this.publisherCallback.bind(this));
  }

publisherCallback(error, response) {
    
      if (error) {
        this.logger.log(error);
      }

 this.callbackResponse = response; // need this response in component once received here.
}
```

It returns null;

Comment: Can you please provide the implementation of the method `publishToChannel` ? And please add the return type to those functions.

Comment: We are using a third party sdk and publishToChannel is a sdk function with 2 parameters publishToChannel(options, callback). There is no return type i check so i need to update a global variable once response received. But how can i notify my component that global variable updated? I have updated my code in main question.

Answer (score 1):

As @JacopoSciampi mentioned, the method `publishToChannel()` needs to itself return a value. You should then await on `publishCallback` to get the value from the latest callback you called. IMO this structure is a little bit redundant and you could simplify this entire structure. You could do:

```
// component.ts
await publishStream()
await publishToChannel()
```